# If A is orthogonal matrix and $(A-I)^2=0$ can A be different than I?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $(A-I)^2=0$ than it minimal polynomial divides $(A-I)^2=0$, so $M_A=(A-I)$ or $M_A=(A-I)^2$. If $M_A=A-I$ than $A=I$, and if $M_A=(A-I)^2$ than A is similar to $$D=\operatorname{diag}(J_2(1),J_1(1),...,J_1(1))$$

But I cannot find any example of orthogonal matrix that it minimal polynomial is $M_A=(A-I)^2$. Does that matrix exists ?

Thanks.

Comment: The title and the body are different questions. Please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$(D-I)^2=D^2-2D+I=0$$
or
$$D^2+I=2D$$
Multiply by $D^T$:
$$D+D^T=2I$$
You have shown that every term of $D$ is $0$ or $1$, so $D=I$.

Comment: why $DD^\top= I$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ must be $I$ by a diagonalisation reduction.

Answer (score 1):

No, if $H=A-I$ and $H^2=0$ you will need the range of $H$ to be within the null space of $H$. If we change coordinate system to decompose the space into the null space and it's complement the matrix $H$ would have zero columns on the left (the null space) and only non-zero elements on the same number of rows at the bottom, that is $H=\begin{pmatrix}0_{c\times c} & 0_{c\times n} \\ h & 0_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$ for some $n\times c$ matrix $h$.

Now if $H\ne 0$ we have that $A = H+I=\begin{pmatrix}I_c & 0_{c\times n} \\ h & I_n\end{pmatrix}$ and we would have non-zero dot products between columns which contradicts the assumtion that $A$ is orthogonal since we have $A^T A = \begin{pmatrix} I_c + h^T h & h^T \\ h & I_n \end{pmatrix}$ where at least $h$ and $h^T$ are non-zero.